# network interface counters not working?

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I just built a router and installed it with Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS. The system has two NICs, one for the internal network and one for the external (`p3p1`) network. I'd like to monitor external interface usage, but the `ifconfig` counters are always at 0. `ip -s link ls p3p1` shows zero for all counters as does `cat /proc/net/dev`. The internal interface (`em1`) counters work fine. According to `lspci`, the external interface is a Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 10).

Other than the counters, it works fine. How do I get the counters working on this device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out the correct Google query to find an answer: it's fixed in kernel 3.14. Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installs kernel 3.13.

[The original bug report](http://www.spinics.net/lists/netdev/msg245544.html)

[Thread stating when it was fixed](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=166555)